# Replace Values of an array with key's of another array. PHP Homework

Tags: php, arrays, forms, implode

Hi there this is a bit hard to word so I'm trying my best to explain what is happening. Pretty much I have a form where I had a selection box. I had to fill it with the following.

```
<?
       $PROVINCES = array("--" => "---Please Select Provinces---",
       "nf"=>"Newfoundland",
       "pe"=>"PrinceEdwardIsland",
       "nb"=>"New Brunswick",
       "ns"=>"Nova Scotia",
       "qc"=>"Quebec",
       "on"=>"Ontario",
       "mb"=>"Manitoba",
       "sk"=>"Saskatchewan",
       "ab"=>"Alberta",
       "bc"=>"British Columbia",
       "nt"=>"Northwest Territories");?>
```

So I did that:

```
    <select name = "province[]" multiple size = "12" <?if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){if (isset($errorList['province']))
    {
    echo "class=\"error\"";
    }}?>>
  <?php foreach($PROVINCES as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"<?= (in_array($key, $_POST['province'] ) )?'selected':'';?>><?php echo $value?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```

Now the next step was to make a table of all the values in $_POST
but the problem is since the values are nf, pe, nb etc it will write those in the table and not PrinceEdwardIsland, New Brunswick, Nova Scotia.

```
echo '<table border="1" style="width:100%">';
    foreach($_POST as $name => $out)
    {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<strong>';
        echo strtoupper($name);
        echo '</strong>';
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td>';

        if (is_array($out))
        {

            count($_POST);


            $arrayOutput = implode(", ", $out);
            echo $arrayOutput;



        }

        else if (strlen($out) <= 0)
        {
            echo "---None supplied---";
        }
        else
        {
        echo $out;
        }
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }


    echo '</table>';
```

But as you can see from here we have multiple different $name from $_POST when we call it in our foreach loop.

And as you can see when I do is_array($out) I implode the array and split it out by ","'s I only need to get the full names for provinces, I had a checkbox for Status and it only has to display what the value in the checkbox was. I'm trying to figure out how I can get the $key of $PROVINCES to replace the imploded values in $_POST['province']

Hopefully I explained it well enough for people to understand.

Comment: Use your `$PROVINCES` array in the output as well. Then you can map up the abbreviation with the name.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Before going that route you cant just have the province as the value?

Comment: I don't really get the problem, it seems that you just rwant to print the names of the provinces, so what's different here from the select window? Just foreach over $out and echo the value?